# How javascript for loop checks statements without iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have list of objects named `data`.

And 1 input tag.

I want to check that if input value exists in data's `person1` key. If exist I write input value and `person2` keys value. Else write `I don't understand`.

How this code gives `true` answer. this is `wrong`.

Try `How old are you` this. If you input this it must give `I don't understand` 2 times and `30`

```js
function SendMessage() {
    var input = document.getElementById('person'),
        sender = document.createElement('p'),
        receiver = sender.cloneNode(true),
        data = [{
            "person1": "Hey",
            "person2": "Hey, How are you?"
        }, {
            "person1": "Hello",
            "person2": "Hello friend"
        }, {
            "person1": "How old are you",
            "person2": "30"
        },
    ];

    sender.innerText = input.value;
    document.body.appendChild(sender);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (input.value === data[i].person1) {
            receiver.innerText = data[i].person2;
            document.body.appendChild(receiver);
            i = data.length;
        } else {
            receiver.innerText = "I don't understand";
            document.body.appendChild(receiver);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="person">
<button onclick="SendMessage()">Send message</button>
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't really understand - what is `wrong answer`, `true answer`, `true` answer, `wrong`. What is the intended purpose? (I can't find anything really wrong with it)